# What are the class names of transitions supported by twitter bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions, transition

What are the class names of transitions supported by twitter bootstrap? I know only one class name of a transition, as used in the example on the website: 'fade' for fading in. What are other class names of transitions supported by twitter bootstrap?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These are the classes for the different transitions:

- `.fade` (fade out)
- `.fade.in` (fade in)
- `.collapse` (collapse out)
- `.collapse.in` (collapse in)

If you use the modal then the fade class adds animation to the modal

- `.fade` (fade out to top 0)
- `.fade.in` (fade in from top to 50% height)